# Output truncated for summary lm() function

Tags: r

On RStudio, I do a linear regression with lm() R function with correlation:

```
lm(NOTE_LICENCE1 ~ (MASCULIN + annee_blocage + NOTE_ORIGINE_PSYCHOLOGIE + NOTE_INTRODUCTION_SOCIOLOGIE + 
                                        PRENOM_SOCIAL +  Redoublant + Abandon + AvanceRetardL1 + 
                                        IsFrench + IsParent + IsHandicap + IsBoursier + IsLogChezParent + 
                                        AvRetBAC + BAC_etranger + BAC_Dispense + BAC_Economique + 
                                        BAC_Professionnel + BAC_Scientifique + BAC_Techno + BAC_mention_AB + 
                                        BAC_mention_B + BAC_mention_TB + DiffAnnee1ereInscrition + 
                                        Situ_annee_precedente_BTS + Situ_annee_precedente_IUT + Situ_annee_precedente_CPGE + 
                                        Situ_annee_precedente_ingenieur + Situ_annee_precedente_enseig_sup_par_corresp + 
                                        Situ_annee_precedente_universite + Situ_annee_precedente_etab_etranger_enseig_secondaire + 
                                        Situ_annee_precedente_autre_etab_en_france + Situ_annee_precedente_non_scolarise_jamais_entre_enseignement_superieur + 
                                        Situ_annee_precedente_non.scolarise_deja_entre_enseignement_superieur + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_diplome_etab_etranger_secondaire + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_dipl_etab_etranger_sup + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_BTS + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DUT + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DAEU + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DEUG + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_attest_fin_annee1_medecine + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_dipl_secteur_param_social + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_autre_dipl_univ_1_cycle + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_licence3 + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_Dipl_univ_3cycle + 
                                        Dernier_dipl_obtenu_autre_dipl_sup + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_aucun_dipl_sup + 
                                        Position.sociale.defavorisee + Position.sociale.moyenne + 
                                        Position.sociale.favorisee.B + Position.sociale.favorisee.A + 
                                        DiffAnneeEntreeSup + filiere_1PS5 + filiere_1SO5) *
                       (MASCULIN + annee_blocage + NOTE_ORIGINE_PSYCHOLOGIE + NOTE_INTRODUCTION_SOCIOLOGIE + 
                       PRENOM_SOCIAL +  Redoublant + Abandon + AvanceRetardL1 + 
                       IsFrench + IsParent + IsHandicap + IsBoursier + IsLogChezParent + 
                       AvRetBAC + BAC_etranger + BAC_Dispense + BAC_Economique + 
                       BAC_Professionnel + BAC_Scientifique + BAC_Techno + BAC_mention_AB + 
                       BAC_mention_B + BAC_mention_TB + DiffAnnee1ereInscrition + 
                       Situ_annee_precedente_BTS + Situ_annee_precedente_IUT + Situ_annee_precedente_CPGE + 
                       Situ_annee_precedente_ingenieur + Situ_annee_precedente_enseig_sup_par_corresp + 
                       Situ_annee_precedente_universite + Situ_annee_precedente_etab_etranger_enseig_secondaire + 
                       Situ_annee_precedente_autre_etab_en_france + Situ_annee_precedente_non_scolarise_jamais_entre_enseignement_superieur + 
                       Situ_annee_precedente_non.scolarise_deja_entre_enseignement_superieur + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_diplome_etab_etranger_secondaire + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_dipl_etab_etranger_sup + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_BTS + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DUT + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DAEU + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_DEUG + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_attest_fin_annee1_medecine + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_dipl_secteur_param_social + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_autre_dipl_univ_1_cycle + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_licence3 + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_Dipl_univ_3cycle + 
                       Dernier_dipl_obtenu_autre_dipl_sup + Dernier_dipl_obtenu_aucun_dipl_sup + 
                       Position.sociale.defavorisee + Position.sociale.moyenne + 
                       Position.sociale.favorisee.B + Position.sociale.favorisee.A + 
                       DiffAnneeEntreeSup + filiere_1PS5 + filiere_1SO5), data = fic)
```

Data file contains 3000 rows.

Despite this instruction options(max.print=999999)
output for summary(lm()) function is truncated in console.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Which summary values are you looking for specifically? Estimates of the relationships, pvalues for the estimates, r-squared for the model...? There are functions that can return model output in a clean format (`broom::tidy`) if youre mostly after model parameters and p-values.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to output to an external file rather than attempting to copy-paste your results from the console.

```
sink("sink-examp.txt")
```

`summary(lm(YOURMODEL))`

```
unlink("sink-examp.txt")
```

This would take the output of the summary call and put it all into a file called "sink-examp.txt"

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, it fixed my trouble!